# Why won't this Python script replace one variable with another variable?

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I have a CSV file with two columns in it, the one of the left being an old string, and the one directly to right being the new one. I have a heap of .xml files that contain the old strings, which I need to replace/update with the new ones.

The script is supposed to open each .xml file one at a time and replace all of the old strings in the CSV file with the new ones. I have tried to use a replace function to replace instances of the old string, called 'column[0]' with the new string, called 'column[1]'. However I must be missing something as this seems to do nothing. If I the first variable in the replace function to an actual string  with quotation marks, the replace function works. However if both the terms in the replace function are variables, it doesn't.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
import os
import csv

with open('csv.csv') as csv:
    lines = csv.readline()
    column = lines.split(',')

    fileNames=[f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.xml')]
    for f in fileNames:
        x=open(f).read()
        x=x.replace(column[0],column[1])
        print(x)
```

Example of CSV file:

```
oldstring1,newstring1
oldstring2,newstring2
```

Example of .xml file:

```
Word words words oldstring1 words words words oldstring2
```

What I want in the new .xml files:

```
Word words words newstring1 words words words newstring2
```

Comment: can you explain yourself a tad better please? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. We'll need to see the content of your csv and xml files.

Comment: Can you print `column` so that we can check its content?

Comment: Yes printing column[1] prints the old string. Printing column[0] prints the new one just fine.

Comment: `.replace()` works with string variables as well as it works with string literals. You have some problems in the code preceding the _replacing loop_.  ፨  Aside, are you sure that you want to do is printing all the `.xml` files to standard output as many times as you have lines in  the `.csv` file?

Comment: No I want to save over the old .xml files, however have just used print for now to try and get it working. When you say there are some problems before the replacing loop, are you able to detail them for me please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is better done using `sed`. However.

If we want to use Python, it seems to me that what you want to do is best achieved

- reading all the obsolete - replacements pairs and store them in a list of lists,
- have a loop over the `.xml` files, *as specified on the command line*, using the handy [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fileinput.html)  module, specifying that we want to operate in line and that we want to keep around the backup files,

  - for every line in each of the `.xml` s operate **all** the replacements,
  - put back the modified line in the original file (using simply a `print`, thanks to `fileinput`'s magic) (`end=''` because we don't want to strip each line to preserve eventual white space).

```
import fileinput
import sys

old_new = [line.strip().split(',') for line in open('csv.csv')]

for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1:], inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    for old, new in old_new:
        line = line.replace(old, new)
    print(line, end='')
```

If you save the code in `replace.py`, you will execute it like this

```
$ python3 replace.py *.xml subdir/*.xml another_one/a_single.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem over here is you are treating the csv file as normal text file not looping over the all the lines in the csv file.

You need to read file using csv reader

Following code will work for your task

```
import os
import csv
with open('csv.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fileNames=[f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.xml')]
    for f in fileNames:
        x=open(f).read()
        for row in reader:
            x=x.replace(row[0],row[1])
        print(x)
```

Comment: I tried this as it was easier for me to read, however I think the way I have done the os.listdir isn't very compatible with the large files I am using. The .xml files are around 10Mb while the CSV file is around 7000 lines long and it is freezing up the computer.

Comment: It is freezing due to the nested loop of replace that is running 7000 times. You can do all the replacements simultaneously using regex library.